# Undefined subroutine &main::remove_tree call

Tags: perl

I am writing a perl script that would send email about a the number of open cases and at the sametime will delete a directory which is more than 30 days old.

```
 $age = -M;
if($age > 30)
{
    remove_tree ($_);
}
```

This is what I am doing.Teh script was running fine but after 30 days It stopped running,not deleting the old directories and throws the following error.

```
 Undefined subroutine &main::remove_tree called at /var/www/cgi-bin/remedy-case- 
  management/remedy-open-cases-script.pl line 35.
```

Not sure How i solve this.

I removed the paranthesis from remove_tree line and it throws error as follows.
   Can't call method "remove_tree" without a package or object reference at /var/www/cgi-bin/remedy-  case-management/remedy-open-cases-script.pl line 35.

Can anyone let me know what error i am making here?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove_tree` is a function in [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html).

Be sure to include that module before using the function:

```
use File::Path qw(remove_tree);
```

Comment: Oh sure. I didnt know that..I accepted your answer..How do I vote.?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you removed or commented out a line similar to

```
use File::Path qw{ remove_tree };
```

See [File::Path](http://p3rl.org/File::Path).